# What is written on the wall in this scene of The Danish Girl?

Tags: analysis, translation, the-danish-girl

I am from India and curious to know what is written on the wall. I am not familiar with these fonts and this language.

[image]

Comment: I've re-tagged the question for you. The text looks to me like it's in German, but unfortunately, I don't speak German. When I get some time, I'll see if I can at least transcribe it, so that someone else can provide a translation for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's German, written in [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur).

The two bottom lines are a part of one of  [Jalāl ad-Dīn Muhammad Rūmī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumi)'s (known as Rumi) [ghazals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghazal) translated by Friedrich Rückert. The full text of this poem is

> Rein gehalten dein Gewand, Rein gehalten Mund und Hand.
>
> Rein das Kleid von Erdenputz, Rein von Erdenschmutz die Hand.
>
> Rein von Erdentrutz das Herz, Und von Gier der Lippe Rand.
>
> Außen sei die Schwelle rein, Innen rein des Hauses Wand;
>
> Daß einsprechen könn' im Haus Reiner Gast aus Himmelsland.
>
> Reiner Schmaus und reiner Kelch, Rein von Rauch des Herdes Brand.
>
> Sohn! die äußre Reinigkeit Ist der innern Unterpfand.
>
> Rein gehalten Hand und Mund! Rein gehalten dein Gewand.

I coudn't find the English translation. An automatic translation with a tiny bit of editing is as follows:

> Keep your robe clean, keep your mouth and hand clean.
>
> Pure the dress of earth plaster, pure from earth dirt the hand.
>
> Pure of earth tripping the heart, And of greed the lip edge.
>
> Outside, be the threshold pure, inside be pure the house wall;
>
> That could speak in the house. Pure guest from heavenland.
>
> Pure Meals and pure goblet, pure from smoke of the stove fire.
>
> Son! the external purity is the internal pledge.
>
> Keep your mouth and hand clean, keep your robe clean.

---

The two upper lines (thanks to *MissMonicaE*, I didn't even realize they are not from the poem) are "*Operation ist Technik, Anzeigestellung ist Wissenschaft*" - "*(Surgery) Operation is technique/craftmanship. Making decision about the necessity of operation is a science*". Interestingly, Google auto-fills this phrase but there is only one page with exactly this text - lectures or correspondence of the German gynecological society [published in 1908](https://archive.org/stream/verhandlungen00gyngoog/verhandlungen00gyngoog_djvu.txt).

Comment: Above the poem it says *Operation ist Technik! Anzeigestellung ist Wissenschaft!* which means "Operation is technique! Indicating position [??] is science [or scholarship]!"

Comment: @MissMonicaE Oh, I didn't even realize that two upper lines aren't from the poem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to translate *Anzeigestellung*; it's not in my dictionary and the uses I've found on the web are the position an item is displayed in in the store ("make sure the price is visible in the display position") or the position of some kind of indicator mechanism.